# prevent pasting of single and double quotes in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to prevent the single and double quotes from being pasted in a text area in javascript

HTML

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="10" id="txtTest"></texarea>
```

Preventing the single and double quotes on keydown

```
$('#txtTest').on('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 222 || e.keyCode == 222){
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

How to prevent the same when the text is pasted. (ctrl + v)

Comment: should be `</textarea>` (T typo)

Comment: Check my solution for any of the System-paste events(**KEYBOARD+MOUSE**). Trap and remove quotes instantly when PASTE occurs. Check the **DEMO** too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to trap more than the keydown event - Ctrl+V or right-click and paste can also insert characters (well and the older Shift+Insert).  Depending on your usage, you may want to remove unwanted characters before submission.  However, if you want it on the event, then trap all events and replace the text with the cleared text, depending on the event type.

```
$('#txtTest').val($('#txtTest').val().replace(/['"]/g, ''));
```

That'll remove all the single and double quotes (though not "smart" quotes).

Answer (score 2):

listener to input event

```
var t = document.getElementById("text");
t.addEventListener("input", function (){
    var str = this.value;
    if (str.search(/'|"/g) !== -1) {
        alert("\'\"is not allowed");
    }
}, false);
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EZXqH/

Comment: This certainly isn't removing the ' and ".

Answer (score 2):

may be this: http://jsfiddle.net/patelmilanb1/7NfLV/1/

```
$('#txtTest').on('keypress', function (e) {
        var ingnore_key_codes = [34, 39];
        if ($.inArray(e.which, ingnore_key_codes) >= 0) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

Comment: you should also not be able to PASTE in.

Answer (score 1):

Besides coding the logic you have to think how to invoke the code at proper time. Here is a demonstration for that. On every system-paste event(***either mouse or key board***) the following code will run and do the operation. No need of any `ASCII code`.

Use the following:

```
$('textarea').on('paste', function () {
    var element=$(this);
  setTimeout(function () {
    element.val(element.val().replace(/['"]/g, ""));
  }, 1);
});
```

Check **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x7zxT/)**